# PyQt5 gets "No module named 'PyQt4'" error calling matplotlib.pyplot in Python 3.5

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5

I am using Anaconda with Python 3.5.2, Matplotlib 2.0.2, PyQt5.6 on a windows 10 machine. When I  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt I get the following error:

```
...
File "C:...\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\qt_compat.py", 
           line 137, in <module> from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

ImportError: No module named 'PyQt4'
```

I don't know why it would want to import from PyQt4 when it has never been installed on my machine.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16994232/importerror-no-module-named-pyqt4) question has the same error, but on a machine that actually has PyQt4 installed.

I have checked my matplotlibrc file, I've used `matplotlib.use('qt5agg')` in the program, also `matplotlib.rcParams['backend'] = "Qt5Agg"`. I've uninstalled and reinstalled all the above packages to no avail. I have even attempted to install PyQt4 just to get things going. I'm completely stumped. None of the various possible causes or remedies that I've been able to find on either SO or github have helped.

Comment: You need to install PyQt4 with pip. your version of matplotlib requires PyQt4. See http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/installation.html on how to install

Comment: No, it doesn't make sense to install PyQt4 if PyQt5 should be used. Can you try `import matplotlib; matplotlib.use("Qt5Agg"); matplotlib.rcParams["verbose.level"] = "debug"; import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` and see if further information is given which you can post here?

Comment: The error is the same, essentially. The backend actually gets set to qt5agg.py but then as above, It starts looking for qt4 after the call to qt_compat.py.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same error (even though on Windows 7). For me the problem was that there was an old `matplotlibrc` file in `C:\Users\<username>\.matplotlib\matplotlibrc` which overwrote the settings from my environment's `matplotlibrc` file. Deleting that file solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the API version is PyQt5 but the default is PyQt4,just open Tools -> Preferences -> IPython console -> Graphics -> backend,change QT4 to QT5

Comment: Which program are you in when you refer to open Tools->...?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the file and line number in your error it looks that you have the same issue that I answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40573234/625350).

That is, I think your issue is caused by having a `QT_API` environment variable that still is set to `pyqt4` (or `pyside`).

Comment: Thanks. I get "None" in response to `print(os.environ.get('QT_API'))`.

Comment: Have set system variable and now get "pyqt5" in response to `print(os.environ.get('QT_API'))`. Error remains though.

Comment: The way forward is to look in `qt_compat.py` and try to debug why it tries to import PyQt4 at line 137. The best way is to copy `qt_compat.py` to a temporary directory and then, from that directory, start `python -m qt_compat`. This should give you the same error, but now you can add some print statements to the copy of `qt_compat.py` that make it easier to debug the issue. The line above the import says `if QT_API in [QT_API_PYQT, QT_API_PYQTv2]`. Start by printing the value of the `QT_API` global variable at that point. I'm sure you can make some progress from there.

Comment: Now I'm getting,  `c:...\qt_compat.py(127)<module>()
-> from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
(Pdb)
> c:\...\qt_compat.py(128)<module>()
-> _getSaveFileName = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName
(Pdb)
AttributeError: module 'PyQt5.QtWidgets' has no attribute 'QFileDialog'`. In QtWidgets.pyw there is class QFileDialog. I'm at the limit of my expertise. I'm considering a complete uninstall/reinstall of anaconda.

Comment: What a mess :-). I must say that I don't have a clue what could cause that last issue. Perhaps a reinstall is a good idea, or you could first try in a new conda environment where you only install what's needed.

Comment: I've gone with the reinstall option but am now having a related issue. Everything was fine until I imported a package that worked perfectly before and I'm getting a similar error to the above:` module blahblah has no attribute...` when, indeed, it does. It's as if Python has lost the ability to look inside the packages or become blind to what is in there. Anyway, a note of thanks for your time on this.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar thing and found that the problem was having a 64-bit Anaconda installation that couldn't load the PyPt5 DLLs that were perhaps 32-bit. The short answer is that I uninstalled Anaconda 64-bit and installed the 32-bit version instead.

To work through this, I stepped through qt_compat.py where the error originates. For most of the time through this module, it’s trying to work with PyQt5, as that’s what it finds in the environment. However, when it gets to the lines below, the import fails so it tries to fall back to PyQt4, which isn’t installed with Anaconda, and thus issues the error.

```
if QT_API == QT_API_PYQT5:
    try:
        from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
        _getSaveFileName = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName
    except ImportError:
        # fell through, tried PyQt5, failed fall back to PyQt4
        QT_API = rcParams['backend.qt4']
        QT_RC_MAJOR_VERSION = 4
```

Testing the import statement outside of the file gave the message “DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.” That's what suggests the DLL mismatch, and also answers why it was trying to fall back to PyQt4.

Answer (score 0):

3 steps can solve this problem:

```
pip uninstall pyqt5
pip uninstall matplotlib
pip install matplotlib
```

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same problem and here is how I fixed it.

Look into your matplotlib configuration file which is often located at 
path-to/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/matplotlibrc 
or 
path-to/Anaconda3/envs/your_env_name/Lib/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/matplotlibrc

See an example of matplotlibrc here
https://github.com/daler/matplotlibrc/blob/master/rc/default

If you have pyqt5.x.x installed and have the statement 'backend    : Qt5Agg' in matplotlibrc, then to use '%matplotlib qt', change '#backend.qt4 : PyQt4' to '#backend.qt4 : PyQt5'.

For an Anaconda environment, reactivate the environment.

Note if you update matplotlib in the future, your matplotlibrc will automatically be overwritten.