# Importing matplotlib.pyplot - requiring pyqt4? Python 3.5.2

Tags: python, qt, matplotlib

I'm having issues import matplotlib.pyplot. I recently updated to Python 3.5.2. The error it gives me is as such:

> ImportError: Matplotlib qt-based backends require an external PyQt4, PyQt5,
>       or PySide package to be installed, but it was not found.

So I install PyQt5 using `pip install pyqt5`, and I successfully install it. I run my code again, and then I get a different error:

> ImportError: No module named 'PyQt4'

So I use pip (`pip install pyqt4`) and attempt to install it. I get another error saying that PyQt4 can not be installed in the command prompt:

> (User) C:\Users\Username>pip install pyqt4
>
> Collecting pyqt4
>
> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyqt4 (from versions: )
>   No matching distribution found for pyqt4

So my question is, is what do I need to do to be able to import this package?

Comment: Place this 2 lines in the initial part of the file: `import matplotlib`

`matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')`

Comment: No luck - still getting the same error.

Comment: could show the code you are using and where you have placed what I suggested.

Comment: If you have pyqt5 installed, you don't need pyqt4 for running matplotlib. It will require either of them, not both. I'm not sure but I think installing pyqt4 for python3 is not straight forward, so don't dive into this if you don't have to. There is also a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44051058/pyqt5-gets-no-module-named-pyqt4-error-calling-matplotlib-pyplot-in-python-3?rq=1) being asked here.

Comment: Your code should have the following form: `import matplotlib` `matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')` `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`

Comment: `import matplotlib` `matplotlib.use(Qt5Agg')` `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest those were my exact thoughts - why would I have to install PyQt4 if I have installed PyQt5 installed? The link you posted is the exact problem I'm having.

Comment: So did you try any of the solutions there? Even if they fail, the information about what you tried are usefull for others to further help.

Comment: I did try the solutions that were suggested, but to no avail. Hopefully it works for someone else!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to install PyQt4, even though I have PyQt5. Using

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

did not work in my case.

Comment: Same for me. Neither Pyside, Pyside2 or PyQt5 worked. I installed PyQt4 with the package manager, `sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt4` and it worked.